# Do we have a troll here?

Tags: discussion

```
I am not only saying Lorentz Einstein and the 100,000 dead physicists and the
100,000 living physicists are wrong I am adding that the collective value of
relativity theory special and general and all of more than three dimensions based
physics is 1/2 rotten onion stinking onion.
```

From [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/length-contraction-in-rotating-frame/10856#10856). No Latex (ok, newbie here I guess), poor grammar, and the (I think) arrogant tone of that sentence makes me think this guy doesn't want real discussion on his ideas.

Also, his other answers don't seem to deal much with the questions being asked. In a discussion of Hooke's law he still irrelevantly brings up relativity and why it's wrong. Do you guys think he's just a troll/someone wanting to cause trouble here?

EDIT: his answer has been deleted. Oh well.

Comment: the quoted text is clearly 100% rant, even if you know nothing about the topic

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He certainly is.

I remind the official way of dealing with trolls:

1. Ignore -- don't try to talk with such people, it is useless and only makes them troll more.
2. Downvote to notify other users about the quality of the post. Downvoting Qs is free, -1 for answer downvote have a great chance of being refunded (when the post is deleted).
3. Flag if the post is useless junk without discussion and can be safely removed.

Comment: Nice answer, I completely agree. Especially with the part about ignoring. It doesn't really do much good to deal with a troll publicly; posting on meta about it doesn't accomplish anything that flagging the post wouldn't.

Comment: Agreed. Also, I recently learned about [hellbanning](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html), that'd be so evil and yet adequate sometimes... (@david, too)